# Can a sql query that uses For XML be tweaked to add xml definition at the start of it's output

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Hi I have a sql query that utilises FOR XML.  The query works perfectly, both in its original form and several variants I've produced.

I now want to be able to take the results of this query and have it displayed directly into an Actipro syntax editor so that it can be nicely formatted for the end user so that they can take advantage of the editor's ability to navigate through the created xml document.

For this to work properly I really need the sql query to output as the first like of the result the following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for tweaking the query to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is not possible to add [processing instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) in the FOR XML clause. Besides, adding the `encoding="UTF-8"` would be plain wrong, since the XML returned is **not** UTF-8 encoded (SQL Server does not support UTF-8 in any form).

I recommend you add the desired PI in client side processing, **along with actual conversion to the desired encoding**.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  I'd hoped it would be possible, but no matter, I can do it on the client side. I was just looking for a way to save time.